# Firestore query returns nothing

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Here is the structure of the firestore database

ingredients->(doc name)-> ingredientName: "Apple"

I am trying to figure out the document name of the document with Apple in it but I keep running into an issue where nothing is returned.

```
async function getIngredientID(){
    const q = query(collection(fsdb, 'ingredients'), where('ingredientName', '==', 'Apple'));
    const querySnapshot = await getDocs(q);
    querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
        console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());
    });
}
```

there is nothing that comes out on the console. At one point I console logged the value of q and there was no document there. All of the StackOverflow answers have to do with Web version 8 but I am working with Web version 9.

Comment: Logging `q` will not be helpful, as that query has not been executed.  It is just an object describing a query.  Any query results will be in `querySnapshot`.

Comment: Could you provide us a complete and a reproducible code for us to help you further? How are you executing the async function, you can't execute the async function with only just the provided snippet in your question. Also, provide us your `package.json` to check what version you are using. See [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

I imagine you must have the imports, make sure you have them all correctly. Now import >>fsdb<< make sure to start cloud firestore and get a reference to the service, check that the where method is correct as well as the collection, i don't know what information it has when initializing firebase, it would be nice if you could send more information, if this information does not help you

```
import { collection, getDocs, query, where } from "firebase/firestore";

import { fsdb } from '../fb';

async function getIngredientID() {
  try {
    const q = query(
      collection(fsdb, "ingredients"),
      where("ingredientName", "==", "Apple")
    );

    const { docs } = await getDocs(q);

    const data = docs.map((doc) => ({
      id: doc.id,
      ...doc.data(),
    }));
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
}
```

Comment: What else would you need? so the imports that you have listed are correct except that the fsdb comes from from '../fb' and that is where my firebase config is located. Also your suggestion returns an empty array

Comment: send me how your firebase setup is on a screenshot

Comment: send me a database capture, and also check the security rules